# Count how many tests to find duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be 50.000 scanned texts, some of which are duplicates. A test can be done by a person to look at 10 scanned texts at the same time, and find duplicates.

What would be the best algorithm to loop through all the scanned texts to find duplicates, and how many tests would have to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case (where you don't find any duplicates until the last comparison), every text must be compared to every other text.  If there are $50000$ texts, 
there are ${50000 \choose 2} = 1249975000$ pairs.  Each $10$-tuple has ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ pairs.  Thus you'd need at least $\lceil  1249975000/45 \rceil = 27777223$ $10$-tuples.

A better plan might be to use sorting rather than just checking for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. And how about the algorithm to choose which 10 texts to test so that a given pair is not checked twice ?

Comment: @jayIV, that may or may not be possible.  For example, with 20 texts it is not possible.

Comment: @Wildcard Could  you please elaborate on that ? And if it's not possible, what's the best algorithm to have the least amount of pairs checked multiple times, and what would the total number of tests be with this best algorithm ? (more than 27777223 I assume?)

Comment: @jayIV, is this homework?  My comment should be pretty obvious.  ${20 \choose 2} = 190$.  45 doesn't go evenly into 190.  Have you tried to write an algorithm?  Is this a real problem you're facing?  I don't mean to be curt but if you better conveyed that *you* have tried working at the problem, I'd be more open to follow ups.

Comment: No it's not homework, and yes it could have been a real problem, but another unrelated solution was found to solve it. I was just curious how long it would have taken if we had followed this path.

Comment: @jayIV, ah.  Then my answer is, long enough to realize you should just sort the texts to begin with, as suggested in this answer.  :)  But it is an interesting question, actually.  I recommend you look into "block design" as a relevant subject ripe with interesting data.